# Photoshop-like scripting framework

Tags: java, graphics, rendering, photoshop, layer

I'm looking for a tool, library of framework (preferrably for Java) that allows me to render raster graphics in a layered fashion. Basically, a programmable Photoshop-like API with support for layers, filling areas, transparency, blur/noise filters, drop shadows, inner shadows, etc. It doesn't have to have all of photoshop's features of course.

Does such a framework exist? I can live with it being a command-line tool too, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first think that comes to mind is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) for which there's also a Java API, [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org). Not sure if it can do all you want.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a stretch but you could, in theory, script the graphics engine that [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) uses.

It's probably *way* overkill and I'm sure there are other, better, libraries and ways to do it, but it's the first thing that jumped into my head. On the up-side, it's nearly as powerful as Photoshop and can do tons of things with raster images.